# Passing large JSON from JSP to Angular scope

Tags: javascript, json, jsp, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a i18n.jsp in which i have a large JSON declared using c:set.

`

```
<c:set var="Label" scope="session">
  <json:object escapeXml="false">
    <json:property name="submit"> Submit </json:property>
    <json:property name="cancel"> Cancel </json:property>
    <json:property name="step0NextStepButton">
        <cms:txt code="step0.nextStepButton" />
    </json:property>
    <json:property name="step0NextStepButtonTooltip">
        <cms:txt code="step0.nextStepButton.tooltip" />
    </json:property>
        .....etc
  </json:object>
<c:set>
```

`

And this JSP is included in another JSP which in displayed to the user.
What i want is to put this JSON object ${Label} on the angular's scope.
If i use ng-init="Label=${Label}" the html will break.
I want to avoid ajax call and i want to avoid to put on the $window and then take it in angular from $window object (this is the current implementation).

I saw that in JADE is something like this: ng-init="users= #{JSON.stringify(users)}" and i am wondering if is there anything like this in JSP as well?